# Respond to a get request in java using a database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to respond to a get request in java using a database. But it throws some error which I don't know a clue how to fix it.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException{
        try{
            //Accessing driver from the JAR file 
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance (); 

            //Connect to Clockie's database
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "root", "root");

            //Here we create our query
            String sql = "" +
                    "SELECT * " +
                    "FROM profiles " +
                    "WHERE profileId = '27'";
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            String xmls = "";

            result.next();
            xmls = result.getString("firstName") + " "+result.getString("lastName");
            System.out.println(xmls);

            resp.getWriter().println(xmls);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is fine though, if I set the doGet code block inside the a main method? I'm new to Java pls help!

EDIT:

the exception is "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print out the full stack trace using `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch block.

You may not have the mysql-connector jar which contains `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` on your classpath. Check your classpath by printing it out using:

```
System.out.println("classpath = " + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

Comment: i have added it to the classpath, otherwise the codeblock will not have worked if I placed it inside a main method. e.printStackTrace(); is not working, beacause the method is void.

Comment: @Woho87 instead of `System.err.println(e.getMessage());`, use `e.printStackTrace()` and tell us the complete error.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 .....

Comment: And this exception happens after I refresh my website

Comment: Do I need to add something to my web.xml, outher than servlet mapping it to my class file? I'm new to Java as you can see

Comment: @Woho87 you need to place the mysql jar inside the WEB-INF/lib directory and it should automatically be picked up by tomcat.

Comment: OK thanks @dogbane! Is this with all libraries I want to add?

Comment: yes, all the libraries required by your webapp, go in WEB-INF/lib. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html for more info on how tomcat loads libraries.